# H-bridge as an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, h-bridge

I need to design an amplifier that will amplify the output from DAC. The signal is a triangle from 0V to 1V (tuneable) and I need to get output between -Ucc and Ucc. The problem is that the amplifier is powered by a Li-Ion cell phone battery (e.g. not symmetric). The load is a coil that creates a magnetic field for my measurement.

The absolute must is, that the field created must change smoothly with small increments/decrements without peaks, between -Hm to Hm, that imposes the same for the current.

After research I found that an H-bridge like design, may provide required functionality, with the exception, that each design of H-bridge I found, is based on PWM like control and transistors are in the switching mode. This approach works for electric motors, but will not create the desired results in my case.

I believe that one can set transistors not to switching mode, but to their linear amplification mode and to drive them in contra-phase (shifted by 180 degrees) by the DAC output. I think it will create seesaw like effect on the load coil, where current will flow in one direction during one half period and in opposite direction in second half period, regardless the asymmetric power source.

Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

**EDIT I.**
@tobalt My serious concern is really to get very smooth current profile through the coil. I'm not sure what you mean with "magnet will also do it" ... I have no magnet, just an aerial coil that creates a magnetic field. The issue is that even each step from DAC creates parasite signals. I considered to smooth signal from PWM and very possibly for some triangle periods it will work, but by changing the frequency the capacitors will not be optimal. My measurement depend pretty much on time variation of the magnetic field dH/dt and it may compromise the measurement precision.

I'll ask differently, why do you believe that the chip like LM4871 would not work ? It has two amps, one amplifying signal, another changing the phase and they work in bridge setup. I cannot test it now, as delivery time for these chips is several weeks.

In any case I'll also check the class D amplifiers.

**EDIT II**
Following advises I move my "partial solution" here to the question. Following the LM4871 documentation (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4871.pdf?ts=1630171668912&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) specially the Figure 3 on top of second page, I tend to believe that the chip like that may provide a solution that I'm looking for. I ordered chips (**will take 3 weeks**) to test and I'll update this question with information if it behaves as I need or not.

Comment: Not possible. 1st weird think is that you want to drive a coil with a triangle shape, without mentioning is the shape of current or voltage. 2nd How do you mean not-symetric? A bridge shifts the polarity. 3rd "I believe that one can set transistors not to switching mode" then this would be the audio amplifier, not a H-bridge.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I got the picture, of what you wish to have, but foggy. :-)  Could you draw some waveform, a block diagram, input output electrical spec, the application, the purpose, and whatever can help us understanding the device/system you'd build, please?

Comment: You might search for *linear bridge amplifier*. However, be aware that most power amplifiers of this type are **voltage sources** rather than the **current source** that you require.

Comment: An H bridge in linear mode is essentially two Class AB amplifiers opposing each other. There are integrated Class AB stages for small powers, e.g. BUF634

Comment: Thanks All for comments. It's true, I'm physicist, not electronics expert, thus my description was foggy as @jay said. The physics background is to create magnetic field relatively slowly changing between two extreme values in one and in opposite direction. As power source is a battery, I needed some setup that will able to get current in one, and in opposite direction. I think that tobalt caught what I wanted to describe. jay I'll try to provide you some diagrams to make my problem clearer. And I'll also try to look to advices of glen_geek and tobait

Comment: If the power source is a battery, you probably want efficiency. A class-D amplifier (H-bridge under PWM) could provide much better energy efficiency than a linear amplifier. What’s wrong with PWM?

Comment: Indeed a class D would be the way to go IMO. you can smooth the PWM into a continuous excitation and the magnet will also do that by itself to some extent

Comment: What you want is a push-pull audio amp type output stage, with each transistor operating in AB mode so as to reduce/eliminate crossover distortion, though it will some design expertise to get that to work with a single supply.  Ones I've dealt with in the past had symmetric + & - supplies, like +12 V and - 12 V.